# BAIKAL reset admin password

Tags: caldav

I installed Baikal and worked with it happily, now I want to enter the Dashboard, and I found out that the admin password does not work any more.
Is there a way to reset the admin password in Baikal ?

Comment: Why is this question off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of reading the code I found it out.
In the Folder "Specific" there is the file called "config.php" where you find in line 50 something like this :

```
# Baïkal Web admin password hash; Set via Baïkal Web Admin
define("BAIKAL_ADMIN_PASSWORDHASH", '337b0e836452d3be49401c0ee9705470');
```

you must replace this hash with **aac7673e041d3a5cbd185924a5ac03f5** and you will be able to log in using the password 'changeme'.